# Is there any package like einsum which could with symmetry?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I have some tensor contractions, e.g., `A[abcd] B[abcd] = C`, where `A[abcd]=A[badc]`and `B[abcd]=B[badc]`.

I checked the manual of `einsum` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html, but did not find any option of symmetry.

Is there any option in `einsum` or other package can handle this symmetry, preferably by python/julia, that could make the contraction faster?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if there is anything that can take advantage of the symmetry and make the operation faster? Why don't you want to use einsum here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for clarifying this! I checked einsum but did not find any option about symmetry.

Comment: There are some routines in the BLAS/ATLAS kinds of libraries that are optimized for symmetry.  I vaguely recall a SO discussion about `matmul` being able to detect symmetry in some cases and using this.  But in general `numpy` code does not do anything special for symmetric arrays.

Comment: Usually fourth-order tensors don't have a lot of optimizations unless they are super-symmetric, i.e. not only is `A[abcd]=A[badc]` but also `A[abcd]=A[acbd]`.  In that case you can change basis from a fourth-order tensor to a second-order one, or even do a spectral decomposition.